# Facebook - let another page (or app) post to timeline of a page instead of to "Visitor posts"

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

Facebook lets you be logged in as a page so when you post things it can be as the page name instead of your personal name.

Is there some way to be able to post to a page's timeline as another page?  When I tried it, it shows up in the visitor posts area instead - I'm assuming this is because the page isn't an admin of the other page (I'm not sure if that's even possible).  As such, the closest I could get was to log in as the destination page and share a post that the other page made, but that's not an ideal solution because of how it looks.

Does anyone know how to be able to get the post to show up on the timeline directly?  Perhaps the key is being able to grant the other page admin permission (I don't know how to do that though)?  Any ideas?

If an app can be used to do this, that could be an option.  The main goal here is to be able to post to the destination page as a different name.  So if I could give the app a name and post to the page as that app's name, that would be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this currently is: 
1. Navigate to the Page on which you would like to post. 
2. Choose to post as your page from the drop down menu at the top right of the 'Status' section (see attached picture). 
3. Write and post your status.

[image: Example]

Comment: I think I tried that but it ended up not showing on the timeline but rather in the area on the left that is for posts from other users.  Does it work for you?  Any thoughts on what I may have done wrong? Thanks

Comment: It worked for me, it might be the other page's settings.

Comment: Would you be able to post a screenshot of a successful post that you made as another page in your page's timeline?  Did you actually do the trick where it shows up in visitor posts and then you share it from there?  I tried this again and couldn't get it to post directly to the timeline. Thanks